# Java Generics example- I dont get this?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have a class called `Car` and within another class (the name doesn't matter) I want to create a generic vector, which can accommodate type `Car`. However, I obviously want this vector to use generics and so be something like `Vector<E> myVector` etc. Assume the class `Car` has a method `getCarMake()`.

If I had the following:

```
    public class myClass<E> {

        Vector<E> myVector = new Vector<E>();

        for(i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++){
           Car tempCar = myVector.get(i);
       sysout(tempCar.getCarMake());
    }
```

when I change `Car tempCar` to `E tempCar`, it wont allow me to call `tempCar.getCarMake()` without performing a cast of type `Car` on `tempCar`?? Surely there is away around this, or it wouldnt be very generic?

I wanted to have:

```
for(i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++){
   E tempCar = myVector.get(i);
   sysout(tempCar.getCarMake());
}
```

Comment: We need to see how you're declaring `myVector`. The code is meaningless without that.  Also, what is `E`? These identifiers are no use without context.

Comment: Do you declare E as extending Car ?

Comment: Generics are for when you want to write a class once, but have it apply to multiple types of data.  Is that what you have here?  If the only data you're working with is type `Car`, then you don't want a *generic* implementation, you want a *parameterized instance*: an instance of `Vector<Car>`.  Conversely, if you do want a *generic* implementation, then why do you think it should only work with type `Car`? What about types like `Horse` or `PowerPlant` or `Date`?

Comment: Paul, the use of generics depends on the point of your code. Thus, in that respect, the name of this class does matter. If you are only internally using `Car`, then you should use @Bart van Heukelom's solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply create your `Vector` like this

```
Vector<Car> myVector = new Vector<Car>();
```

<s>By the way, if you're using a recent Java (younger than about 8 years)</s> *(stupid me, this is a generics question, of course you are)* it'd be better to use `ArrayList` (wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedList` if you need thread-safety, but I don't think you do).

Update: I see you've edited the question. The answer here is simply to change your class declaration to

```
public class myClass<E extends Car> {
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of generics is, that you can write a class that can control the kind of objects you put into it. With a `Vector` generics allow you to control the members, you can put into it. It also makes your code nicer, because you can write code like your first example.

Your second example makes no sense. If you have defined, that your `Vector` can only hold `Car`s, why would you not address them as such?

Comment: I dont want my vector to only hold Car, i'm just saying that is how it was originally being used, is there a way i can make it more generic?

Comment: No, you cannot change a given `Vector`. If you need a completely generic `Vector`, create one using `Vector<Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

Vehicle Container is what you really want.

```
public class VehicleContainer<T extends Vehicle> {

    private Vector <T> vehicleList = new Vector<T>();

    public void enlistVehicles() {
        for (int i=0;i<vehicleList.size();i++) {
            T vehicle = vehicleList.get(i);
            System.out.println(vehicle.getMake());
        }
    }
```

Vehicle is the interface.

```
public interface Vehicle {

    public String getMake();
}
```

and Car is the concrete Implementation.

```
public class Car implements Vehicle {
    public String getMake() {
        return "Audi";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic type E has no meaning without declaring it in the context of either a class or a method. Assuming you had a method that was defined like so --

```
public void <E extends Car> aMethod() {
```

Then you can do this inside that method.

```
Vector<E> carVector = new Vector<E>();
for(i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++){
   E tempCar = myVector.get(i);
   sysout(tempCar.getCarMake());
}
```

Comment: Hi, so what is the point to generics when I have to actually list the name of the Class which I wish to use as the 'E' anyway?

Comment: @Paul You don't always have to, but you do have to if the code inside the method assumes the vector will contain objects that are some from of `Car`, which I'd say makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-thinking your scenario. You defined what you want to do - create a collection that accepts only Car objects. Generics is the Java feature that is going to allow you to do this. Aka, having a collection that accepts only Cars and having a collection that uses Generics is not mutually exclusive, infact they are mutually dependent!

Without Generics you would create a Vector like so:

```
Vector vehicleVector = new Vector();
```

But of course, the collection created would promiscously accept objects of all kinds - rabbits, cars, bikes, bananas ...

But from Java 5 forward we get Generics, which is somewhat misleadingly named, but what it lets you do is enforce, at compile time, a set of object type constraints on other objects. So your code morphs into:

```
Vector<Car> vehicleVector = new Vector<Car>();
```

And now you don't have to worry about all the other pesky object types sneaking into your Car collection! Plus, you get to write less code! The magic that makes this possible *is* Generics. In other words, you already accomplished what you wanted to do :)